# Python: Converting multiple .log files to .csv

Tags: python, csv, logging

I have 174 `.log` files that I need to convert into `.csv`. I'm intermediate beginner in Python, but wanted to create some code to do it in loop rather than manually. All input files are in one folder.

I used some pointers from courses & other forums and the code below creates files in output folder but they are empty. I wonder if the problem is due to use of `'open'` read/write & Pandas `csv_read/df.to_csv` at the same time?

Am I missing something or is there a mistake here? I'd appreciate any help & pointers! I've been staring at it for days now.

As I've said I'm a beginner who just wants to make the life easier by learning Python :)

```
directory = input("Input folder:")
output = input("Output folder:")
txt_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.log')

for txt_file in glob.glob(txt_files):
    with open(txt_file, "rb") as input_file:
        in_txt = pd.read_csv(input_file, names=['Subject','Trial','Event Type','Code','Time','TTime','Uncertainty','Duration','Uncertainty_1','ReqTime','ReqDur','Stim Type','Pair Index'], skiprows=1, delimiter='\t')
        df = pd.DataFrame(in_txt,columns=['Subject','Trial','Event Type','Code','Time','TTime','Uncertainty','Duration','Uncertainty_1','ReqTime','ReqDur','Stim Type','Pair Index'])
        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(txt_file))[0] + '.csv'

        with open(os.path.join(output, filename), 'wb') as output_file:
            df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: What's the point of `with open(os.path.join(output, filename), 'wb') as output_file:` if `output_file` is never used in the `with` block? I think you can just remove the `with` thing altogether and leave just `df.to_csv(filename, index=False)`

Comment: For the sake of debugging and testing, you should remove the loop, focus on 1 file, and work step-by-step until you reach your anomaly (ie your content is empty). Also, as @ForceBru mentionned, you never use the actual file you want to write in

Comment: @ForceBru more like `df.to_csv(os.path.join(output, filename), index=False)`, I think.

Comment: Did the below answer work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
directory = input("Input folder:")
output = input("Output folder:")
txt_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.log')

for txt_file in glob.glob(txt_files):

    in_txt = pd.read_csv(input_file, names=['Subject','Trial','Event Type','Code','Time','TTime','Uncertainty','Duration','Uncertainty_1','ReqTime','ReqDur','Stim Type','Pair Index'], skiprows=1, delimiter='\t')
    df = pd.DataFrame(in_txt,columns=['Subject','Trial','Event Type','Code','Time','TTime','Uncertainty','Duration','Uncertainty_1','ReqTime','ReqDur','Stim Type','Pair Index'])
    filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(txt_file))[0] + '.csv'

    filename = os.path.join(output, filename)

    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: Please  print the `filename` variable and check if it getting values correctly.

Comment: Figured the problem. I missed the `os.path.join` thing. Have updated. It should work fine now. Please check.

Comment: Actually now, all output files are not appearing at all.

Comment: Can you just print the `filename` variable and see if the filename is correct ?

Comment: I've restarted Jupyter and it seems to work now! Thank you!